# Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade not all tags

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to display data in the HTML page. The data is like some code of line. There are some HTML tags like a, p, b etc. I want to display all as a text but only 1  as a tag.

I all ready try {!! $data->text !!} but it's convert all the text in a html tags.

#### Model data

```
public function scopeText()
{
    $text='<a href="#" id="tl">Tag link</a> <p>paragraph</p> 
           <a href="#">Text link</a>';
    return $text;
}
```

#### html.blade.php

```
<div>
    {{ $data->text() }}
</div>
```

#### Right now it show

```
<a href="#" id="tl">Tag link</a> <p>paragraph</p> <a href="#">Text 
link</a>
```

#### when I user {!! !!}

```
Tag link paragraph Text link
```

#### when I user {{ strip_tags($data->text()) }}

```
Tag link paragraph Text link
```

#### when I user {{ strip_tags($data->text(), 'a') }}

```
<a href="#" id="tl">Tag link</a> <p>paragraph</p> <a href="#">Text 
link</a>
```

#### But I want

```
Tag link <p>paragraph</p> <a href="#">Text link</a>
```

only 1 'a' tag want to work as a tag and other things should print as a text.

Comment: did you tried to scape the data like: `<a href="#" id="tl">Tag link\</a\> \<p\>paragraph\<\/p\> 
           <a href="#">Text link</a>'`
And echo it like `{!! YOURDATA !!}`

Comment: @nyu.exe your solution is good but I don't want to edit data. so there is any other solution? Do some predefined function?

Comment: You could make some function to process your data and scape the tags